# Horizontal UIPickerView with animation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipickerview

I was trying to implement an horizontal `UIPickerView` with an animation to decrease and increase size of label during the scroll controlling the position of them, if at the center, and so the selected one, make it bigger than the other, something like this

[image]

What i developed is okay, but I have only one problem, all label change at the same time, I want an animation that change label during the scroll in base of the position, now my picker is like this

https://gph.is/2VCtupV

If you can see all the label change at the same time, I wanted more like a graduation changing, maybe coordinated with the scroll, someone have any idea?! I post the code I used for everything down here:

CollectionCell code

```
import UIKit

class CalendarCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var dayLabel: UILabel!

    var font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            let animation = CATransition()
            animation.type = .fade
            animation.duration = 0.15
            dayLabel.layer.add(animation, forKey: "")
            dayLabel.font = font
        }
    }

    var distanceFromCenter: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            let animation = CATransition()
            animation.type = .fade
            animation.duration = 0.15
            dayLabel.layer.add(animation, forKey: "")
            let percentage = font.pointSize - (distanceFromCenter * 10)
            dayLabel.font = distanceFromCenter != 0 ? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: percentage) : font
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        dayLabel.text = nil
    }

    func initialize() {
        layer.isDoubleSided = false
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

        dayLabel = UILabel(frame: contentView.bounds)
        dayLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        dayLabel.textAlignment = .center
        dayLabel.textColor = .black
        dayLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        dayLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        dayLabel.highlightedTextColor = .black
        dayLabel.font = font
        dayLabel.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleRightMargin]
        contentView.addSubview(dayLabel)
    }

}
```

CollectionView code

```
import UIKit

class CalendarModelPicker: UICollectionView {

    var dateModel: [Int]!

    var currentIndex: Int = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        register(CalendarCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "dateCell")
        delegate = self
        dataSource = self
        backgroundColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}


extension CalendarModelPicker: UICollectionViewDelegate {

}

extension CalendarModelPicker: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dateModel.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dateCell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCollectionViewCell

         let day = String(dateModel[indexPath.row])
         cell.dayLabel.text = day

         return cell
    }

}

extension CalendarModelPicker: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if let cell = cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CalendarCollectionViewCell {
            cell.distanceFromCenter = CGFloat(abs(indexPath.item - currentIndex))
        }
        return CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
}

extension CalendarModelPicker: UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let cellWidthIncludingSpacing = layout.itemSize.width + layout.minimumLineSpacing
        var offset = targetContentOffset.pointee
        let index = (offset.x + scrollView.contentInset.left) / cellWidthIncludingSpacing
        let roundedIndex = round(index)
        offset = CGPoint(x: roundedIndex * cellWidthIncludingSpacing - scrollView.contentInset.left, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
        targetContentOffset.pointee = offset
    }


    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        var visibleRect = CGRect()

        visibleRect.origin = contentOffset
        visibleRect.size = bounds.size

        let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)

        guard let indexPath = indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint) else { return }

        currentIndex = indexPath.row
        collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

Let me know if you know any cocoa to do this or maybe if you can help me with some trick that i still don't know :)

Comment: https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView

Comment: You need to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout and implement layoutAttributes: this will allow you to perform transforms on the cells there, dont do them in the actual cells, the layout attributes method allows you to return .transform.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 do you have any documentation about it? I want to learn more :)

Comment: something like this: https://medium.com/@uthoft.jin/how-to-animate-uicollectionview-using-a-custom-uicollectionviewlayout-a7513add25b2

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)